# How to have text above a row of inline selects in a Bootstrap form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'v been trying to re-create a SEARCH form that looks like this:

http://www.realestate.com.au/

It's the one with a SEARCH bar on top, and multiple SELECTs below it. Also, the label on
each SELECT is above rather than below.

I know in Bootstrap you can add label below like so:

```
<span class="help-block">Some text</span>
```

But how do you add text abovea a row of inline selects?

Could someone please kindly help? I'm using Bootstrap.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place each label and select inside a spanX div, then place the spanX div inside a row container.

Example for three columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      <label for="one">Label One</label>
      <select id="one">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  <div class="span4">
      <label for="two">Label Two</label>
      <select id="two">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
       <label for="three">Label Three</label>
      <select id="three">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

That will come out looking like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you frostyterrier, very kind of you to help.